# change value in datepicker on selection of combo value in yii

Tags: yii, combobox, datepicker

I have a combo box in a form. According to the selected value from combo ,value of date must be changed in datepicker.How to do this?
code goes like this:

```
    <div class="row col2">
<?php $records = CHtml::listData(CodeValue::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'code_lbl','condition'=>"code_type= 'visit_type'")), 'code_id', 'code_lbl');?>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'visit_type'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'visit_type',$records,array('empty' => 'Select Visit Type')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'visit_type'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row col2">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'next_visited_date'); ?>
        <?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute'=>'next_visited_date',

            //'flat'=>true,//remove to hide the datepicker
            'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'drop',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                'showButtonPanel' => true,      // show button panel
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>''
            ),
        ));
      ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'next_visited_date'); ?>
    </div>
```

I have to change the visit date according to visit type selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `ajax` for this:

Change your drop down to use `ajax`, something like:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'visit_type',$records,array(
                                      'empty' => 'Select Visit Type',
                                      'ajax' => array(
                                      'type'=>'POST',
                                      'url'=>CController::createUrl('controller/myAction'),//your controller and action name
                                      'update'=>'#Model_next_visited_date', //replace Model with the model name
                                      'success'=> 'function(data) {
                                        $("#Model_next_visited_date").empty(); //replace Model with the model name
                                        $("#Model_next_visited_date").val(data); //replace Model with the model name
                                      } '
                                      ))); 
    ?>
```

and create a new action:

```
public function actionMyAction()
    {
        //you will receive drop down value in $_POST['Model']['visit_type']
        // Place your date logic here.....
    }
```

Hope that helps